# Ui/Component using plugin in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, plugin, data-provider

I get QA review as below:

```
example/module-mymodule/UiC/DataProvider.php
is too similar to the Magento 2 file
magento/module-cms/magento-module-cms-103.0.0-beta32/Ui/Component/DataProvider.php

Since this file edits public function, you can avoid duplicating code using Magento 2's plugin structure: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html or use class preferences.
```

Can anyone explain, what it try to say?
The file which they refer is below

```
<?php

namespace Example\MyModule\Ui\Component;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting;

/**
 * Component DataProvider
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * @var AddFilterInterface[]
     */
    private $additionalFilterPool;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param Reporting $reporting
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     * @param array $additionalFilterPool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Reporting $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = [],
        array $additionalFilterPool = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            $reporting,
            $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            $request,
            $filterBuilder,
            $meta,
            $data
        );

        $this->meta = array_replace_recursive($meta, $this->prepareMetadata());
        $this->additionalFilterPool = $additionalFilterPool;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated 101.0.7
     * @return AuthorizationInterface|mixed
     */
    private function getAuthorizationInstance()
    {
        if ($this->authorization === null) {
            $this->authorization = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(AuthorizationInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->authorization;
    }

    /**
     * Prepares Meta
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareMetadata()
    {
        $metadata = [];

        /**
        * Instead of Creating Seperate ACl access, CMS authorization is used 'Magento_Cms::save'
        */
        if (!$this->getAuthorizationInstance()->isAllowed('Magento_Cms::save')) {
            $metadata = [
                'mymodule_post_columns' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'editorConfig' => [
                                    'enabled' => false
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
        }

        return $metadata;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function addFilter(Filter $filter)
    {
        if (!empty($this->additionalFilterPool[$filter->getField()])) {
            $this->additionalFilterPool[$filter->getField()]->addFilter($this->searchCriteriaBuilder, $filter);
        } else {
            parent::addFilter($filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it means you don't need to add duplicate code in your module to meet up the customisation. The customisation can be done with the Magento 2 interceptor which known as Plugin. You can apply plugin concept to all the public methods of class in Magento 2.
Hope this will help.